# Word Add In - Caching to Local Path Okay?

Tags: javascript, c#, ms-word, blazor, office-addins

I'm converting a VSTO app I created that very manageable to take the core project to adapt to a specific businesses' needs. Really a side project while I'm going back to college. A good one though.

I'm converting it to a JavaScript add-in to hopefully scale and expand. I'm using Blazor for experience, and to help recycle a lot of bulk core C# code  from my VSTO that does a lot of the heavy CPU work.

My question is, is local IO pretty much not an option with the webpage model? My program uses a lot of personally created json files. It also create a working folder for every word file to help with memory and history control. Will I have to send all of this to a website with a server?

I know HTML naturally uses filePath protection internally through the Web browser. Can I advoid that using Blazor though?

I was thinking about providing a program separate of Microsoft word to run on the users computer and speak to via direct websockets. Innefficiant compared to direct IO, but less data usage the so many HTTP requests to a Website I know have to manage.

The VSTO does use both httpclient request and local directory IO. Mostly IO though.

Thank you for any advice.

As of now, I've spent a lot of time diving into the different limitations of a Balzor and WASB in general. It's a pretty big jump from my mostly back end, and ML coding backgound.

I have a sidehosted Blazor server currently creating and debugging. But I don't think this properly testing the svenerio since I'm probably running the code in Visual Studio with admin permissions.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.